# conditional format cell fill colour using colour defined in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a number of projects that I create a staffing gannt chart for in a sheet called Project Schedule and at the moment I colour each staff member row in the gannt with their role at the company, engineer = green etc. To do this I use the following conditional formatting and have a fill colour defined - repeating for each company role:

`=($F2<=EOMONTH(W$1,0)*($J2>=W$1))*($E2="Production")`

I'd like to change this so it will colour the specified cells based on which project the team member is on rather than their role. In a Project Information sheet I have a list of projects, say project 1, project 2, project 3 etc and I have a cell with a colour associated with the project, green, red, blue. As we move forwards more projects will be added so I'd like to not have to add a new set of conditional formatting for the new project, instead I'd like a way for the gannt chart to fill the row in based on the project matching that on the Project Information sheet and using the associated fill colour from the Project Colour column in the table. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have done two things and recorded a macro around it:

- Fill cell "A1" in highlight yellow
- Create a conditional formatting for formatting "B1" for highlighting that cell in yellow

Hereby the recorded code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With Range("A1").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "a"
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""a"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

The `.Color=65535` is responsible for colouring the cell, which means you can read it and use it for conditional formatting.